# Create, append and submit form using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to implement onclick function, which send parameters using POST method. I need this function to reload the page, what makes me to use some other way than AJAX. I have a function to do this, but this function uses jQuery. Now I need to "port it" to pure JavaScript.

jQuery function:

```
function domainRemoveConfirmation(id, url) {
    //trick to send javascript redirect with post data
    var form = $('<form action="' + url + '" method="post" hidden="true">' +
              '<input type="text" name="domainId" value="'+ id + '" />' +
              '</form>');
    $('body').append(form);
    $(form).submit();
}
```

I look for the equivalent function in pure JavaScript, I need to create element (form with input fields), append it and submit it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here you go:

```
function domainRemoveConfirmation(id, url){
    var myForm = document.createElement('form');
    myForm.setAttribute('action', url);
    myForm.setAttribute('method', 'post');
    myForm.setAttribute('hidden', 'true');
    var myInput = document.createElement('input');
    myInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    myInput.setAttribute('name', 'domainId');
    myInput.setAttribute('value', id);
    myForm.appendChild(myInput);
    document.body.appendChild(myForm);
    myForm.submit();
};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var form = '<form name="myform" action="' + url + '" method="post" hidden="true">' +
          '<input type="text" name="domainId" value="'+ id + '" />' +
          '</form>';
document.body.innerHTML += form;
document.forms.myform.submit();
```

---

```
var f = document.createElement("form");
f.setAttribute('method',"post");
f.setAttribute('hidden',"true");
f.setAttribute('name',"myform");
f.setAttribute('action',url);

var i = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
i.setAttribute('type',"text");
i.setAttribute('name',"domainId");
i.setAttribute('value', id);

f.appendChild(i);


document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);

document.forms.myform.submit();
```