# How do I add a EventListener for a form submit button?

Tags: javascript

How do I add a EventListener for a form submit button?

For example: here is my HTML submit for the form

```
<input type="submit" name="button1" value="Submit" />
```

Here is my various (failed) javascript attempts to run functions on submit:

```
   var x = document.getElementsByTagName("myForm");
   x.addEventListener("Submit", checkInputs());
   x.addEventListener("button1", checkInputs());
   x.addEventListener("submit", checkInputs());
```

For some reason the code runs the functions on refresh/load of page, but not on submit.

Thanks!

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` gets the tags with the name passed you passed into the function. Do you really have a form tag called `"myForm"`? Also, let the event listener call `checkInputs`, don't call it yourself.

Comment: You can try a pure javascript form submit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039477/create-append-and-submit-form-using-pure-javascript

Comment: You don't want a collection of forms, you just want one form, so use `querySelector` and `addEventListener('submit'`

Comment: When you call `checkInputs()` you're *invoking* the function, which is why it's triggering at page load. You simply want `checkInputs` inside of `addEventListener()`.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, I removed the Tag part and am using getElementsByName. I also removed the () from the functions so it's called by the Listener.

It no longer fires upon page load, but they also don't fire when the submit button is pressed.